# Site design, take 2

Tags: discussion, design

There are rumors that the site redesign will happen soon, so I open this thread for some more suggestions, ideas and possible good points of previous design.

Comment: I'd say You started such rumors with this question. :=)

Comment: @Georg On the bright side only ;-)

Answer (score 11):

The present format is fine for me.

The white letters on dark background are not easy for formulae  and copyings. They get too much prominence. It would be OK if only the general background were dark but the answers and comments were black letters on white.

Answer (score 5):

I really liked the font in the blackboard theme (the text one of course).

Comment: I thought it was childish and tacky. Let's stop pretending that there is a blackboard with chalk and instead focus on people using monitors and pixels instead.

Comment: @John The text one.

Answer (score 5):

There is some support for cloning Math.SE; one thing I dislike most about it is this ugly space-waisting header:
[image]

IMO the standard one is way better:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

When is this going to happen?

And I like the layouts at some of the other SE sites.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/

is pretty plain, and has the graph paper background that lots of people like, though I don't like it in particular, but otherwise I like the design.

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Is also nice. It is a little cluttered, but not distracting, and doesn't have anything that would get in the way of math or diagrams. And I like the color scheme.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Looks more readable to me, and has larger fonts, and less cluttered. I like the color scheme here better, but the gray background won't work with math.

So I would be happy with anything that looks like any of these.

What I would like to see the most is: readable text, compatible with math and diagrams, not cluttered, and plain color scheme.

Comment: All I know about when is "soon".

Comment: Don't forget about [tex.se](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) with its background formulas in the site header.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I'm feeling like (almost) anything is better than the current "nothing."

Answer (score 0):

I guess physics is really a very broad subject. Many of us who end up here dont know if their question can be asked on this site( at least the first impression was that for me). I suggest we can have at least a drawing/picture on top carrying the site name along with mini snaps/sketches of variety of physical experiments so as to convey some information to the reader on what this site is about. We can have sketches of
lasers, mirrors, hydron collider(mini), atom, solar system, Einstein(may be) etc. More can be added from different scopes of physics

Answer (score -1):

Never touch a running process. :=(

Comment: It is a design process, some feedback is helpful at any time.

Comment: The usual US engineering aphorism is "if it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Answer (score -2):

Since the site is for undergraduates to research questions, I hope they stick with the current practical theme, rather than changing to a theme that is childish and tacky in pretending to be something which it isn't.

Comment: 1. The site is not *"for undergraduates to research questions"* though they are welcome to do so; and (2) as you have not seen a new proposal it's a bit much to pass judgment on it.

Comment: @dmckee He was [talking about the old theme](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/604/site-design-take-2#comment-1725)

Comment: @Michael, he may have been thinking about the old theme, but this thread is about a possible new one, which he seems to have judged already. Rude and wrong-headed.

Comment: -1. Irrelevant,.!