# Is physics.stackexhange being punished for negative design feedback?

Tags: feature-request, design

I understand that designs take time, and that there are many SE sites that need designs, but I am baffled at why, four months after the original design was withdrawn, a new one hasn't been proposed.

It seems like this will hinder the growth of the site, as we all know that sites without a finished design seem less credible here in 2011.

Is there a plan as to when a second design might be implemented?

Comment: It works fine for me, and I am sure for a lot of people my age group. The point is to get the physics across and it does that fine. My impression is that physicists like utilitarian and not fancy, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @annav I agree about simple design, but I much prefer the polish of http://unix.stackexchange.com/, http://math.stackexchange.com/, or http://tex.stackexchange.com/ in terms of readable fonts and overall user experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no "penalty" -- it's just that I got the strong impression that the Physics community was happy with the sketchy design status quo.

I like the Sketchy design a lot, so that's fine with me. I don't feel there are any negative implications to keeping this design for a while longer.

Comment: I'm not sure if "happy" is quite the right word... I mean, it's not bad, we're fine with it for now, and we definitely do prefer it to the white-on-dark color scheme (which is why it probably seemed that we were very happy with it right after the design was reverted). But still, we are looking forward to the day when Jin gets a chance to do a new custom design for the site.

Comment: Agree; the main problem is that this design strongly suggests this is a beta.

Answer (score 3):

This is of course a question to the team, but I doubt that this is a punishment -- rather Jin is just busy. You may also try contributing constructively to the [design suggestion thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/604/site-design-take-2).

Comment: Yeah, it was understood that by rejecting the original design we would be waiting quite a long time (many months) for a new one. But the usability issues were serious enough that we considered that a necessary compromise.

Comment: @David Not so bad; I was talking with Jin after this and he said we are not on any special bottom of the pile of doom -- but neither a priority.

Comment: right, I meant it was my understanding that it would take some months for him to get through the other sites that needed designs and get back to us naturally.

Comment: thanks for the answer. There's definitely "no punishment" here. I'm a big boy, I can take criticisms just fine. :) It's just there have been a lot of things on my plate recently. Re-designing Physics.se is definitely on my list of todos. As Jeff said, the current sketchy theme serves the site well. But I will definitely create a new theme down the road to give this community its own identity.